# What is the origin of the idea that money is somehow special as far as "fairness" in political thinking?

Tags: history, inequality, income

**What is the origin of development of the idea in political/philosophical thinking that money/wealth is somehow *special* as far as the idea of "fairness"?**

**What are the reasons cited by that development for why wealth is considered somehow special among other things as far as being singled out as needing to be equalized/made fair?**

**Background:**

- Originally, this clearly wasn't a "thing", since in both ancient times (even in Athenian democracy, never mind various kingdoms/empires) there was no concept that there should be "fair"/"equitable" distribution of wealth. In Middle Ages it was the reverse, e.g. the most high aristocracy was exempt from taxes (e.g. hochadel vs. ritters in Germany).
- That clearly changed sometime before the start 20th century and the rise of Progressivism, with the opposite view being a majorly held political view around the world by its end (the only modern political movement that opposes this idea is Objectivism and/or libertarianism - even most right wing/conservative movements support the concept of progressive taxation, with the only beef from conservatives/rightwingers being the degree of progressivity).
- However, what puzzles me about this is, that money is treated specially even though it's NOT the only thing that affects and differenciates people. As a matter of fact, it's not necessarily even the most important thing - for example, see **[Maslow's hierarchy of needs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maslow%27s_hierarchy_of_needs)** where plenty of things have importance above or equal to money.

  Or the fact that from evolutionary biology/evolutionary psychology perspective, access to reproduction is the most important resource any human would care about.

  Yet, nobody ever discusses "fairness" or "equitable" access to those arguably more important non-monetary resources.

  My three favorite examples:

  1. it's 100% clear that some men gather a hugely disproportionate share of sexual favors from women ([Wilt Chamberlain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilt_Chamberlain#Personal_life) or JFK being the equivalent of financial 1%). As noted above, that is a LOT more important to a human than money, yet there is absolutely ZERO notion in any of political or philosophical modern thinking of fairness as far as this area. (please don't cite problems with implementing such equality as a reason - I can come up with numerous possible solutions that may be intrusive, but not hugely objectionable or offensive to modern sensibilities<sup>[1]</sup>).
  2. It's also clear from research that [tall men](https://www.livescience.com/5552-taller-people-earn-money.html), or [good looking women](https://www.businessinsider.com/beautiful-people-get-more-job-interviews-2013-9), have significantly unfair advantage in the workplace (higher wages/more power/better career). But nobody ever objects to this as being unfair and in need of addressing.
  3. People with great talent for sales, persuasion and demagoguery have a clear advantage in selling the ideas advantageous to them (leaving aside whether you agree or disagree with the content of their ideas, a debate between G.W. Bush or Nixon, vs. Bill Clinton or JFK, is 100% preordained on who would win the audience, no matter what the positions they take in the debate).

***please cite any opinions stated to classical thinkers/writers in areas of political science, law or social science etc..., not simply state your own personal reasoning***

---

UPDATE: there were several attempts to prove that my thesis is incorrect and there are indeed efforts to equalize fairly things that aren't money. While I'm open to an answer that takes such a tack, please note that any example must be clearly and demonstrably NOT about money, as follows:

- a specific non-monetary attribute very specifically and targetedly being **denied** to those who have that attribute in abundance; making pains to **NOT** only do so from the rich people who have that attribute but **even from those who are not wealthy**.

  A perfect case of a poor example here would be ADA. Yes, it attempts to ease the life of the disabled. NO, it does NOT do so by "taxing" the abled equally - merely by taxing the wealthy (whether abled or not) - either when taxes pay for it in case of government entities, or shareholders pay for it in case of private ones.
- and grant it to those who have a lack of attribute, again independent of wealth.

  In other words, granting the benefit to only the poor under assumption that the wealthy can purchase said benefit is contrary to the point of what this question is asking.

---

<sub>[1] I was challenged to provide an example of ensuring "more equal" access to sexual favors. I added a couple of them to SamIAm's answer as comments</sub>

Comment: Just to be clear - while a good answer would include the history of how wealth equality arose as idea, the **main** thing I'm interested in is culling out wealth for equality treatment from other unequal things.

Comment: Isn't the prohibition of polygamy (or, to be more specific, polygyny) a form of sexual communism?

Comment: @DVK I don't understand your assertion that money is treated uniquely among necessities. Do people not argue that people deserve equitable access to food, housing, water, and medical care? (Sex is not equivalently a necessity: one does not die without it).

Comment: Also, I'm not sure this qualifies as a real question. It seems more a way to assert the (disputed) premise that money is treated uniquely with regards to other necessities.

Comment: @Avi - sex **is** a necessity. Reproduction is even more so. Sexual competition drives more in humans than anything else (most people would happily go hungry for a day for a chance to have sex). And no, people do not generally argue that people deserve **equitable** access to food/housing/water/medical care. Merely that they deserve **some** access. Nobody advocates that people who live in a 500-room mansion must surrender 30% of rooms in it to homeless.

Comment: @Avi - ... Or that people who gorge themselves on food give up 30% of their food to the hungry (as usual, if someone is high-income but consume very little of sex, food, water or living space, you would tax 30-50% of their income but NOT tax a poorer person who consimes **more** sex, food, water or living space to equalize the latter. So no, your thesis doesn't even remotely hold up.

Comment: @DVK That's because the money gained through taxes is transmuted into things like food and housing. I don't understand how that isn't demanding equitable access to food and housing.

Comment: @Avi - precisely my point. Why take money from high-earning person so low-earning person can get housing, instead of taking housing from high-housing person instead?

Comment: @DVK Because money is fungible and housing isn't.

Comment: It's not clear what you find 'special' about money compared to anything else...other than comparing to physical traits. Which while interesting, isn't really setting up a question to have concrete answers. As for 'fairness' that doesn't have any specific meaning, either. Everyone's opinion of how taxes should be handled is usually based on their own opinion of what they think is fair.

Comment: Avi's point about fungibility is pretty spot-on. That's the primary difference--though I still don't know if that's what you meant by 'special'.

Comment: @DVK well, they do take money from a high-housing person in the form of property tax.

Comment: @SamIam - Several examples of sex equalization programs: (1) Prevent good looking men from accessing online dating services; (2) Even better, tax good looking men and apply taxed money to provide less good looking ones with premium accounts on dating online services - the latter gives you options to make your account be more widely seen; (3) Tax on sex. Payable from those who have more than "fair" to those who have none.; (4) chastity-like device (sorry no links) for men that turns on after detecting more than "fair" # of intercourses in a month.

Comment: @DVK (1) has does not describe execution.  (2) and (3) are money, (4) involves an "Always on" surveillance device, and definitely is "hugely objectionable to modern sensibilities"

Comment: @SamIam - (1) easy. Once a profile gathers a minimum # of likes, views, emails or responses, delete it and bar that IP. (2) No, they are NOT fungible money. They are delivery of sexual selection enhancement (e.g. you don't give money to a person, you give them to a dating site on behalf of a person). (3) Money, but not collected from those with money. And you again can get around thing by explicitly allocating that money to be directly delivered NOT to the beneficiary (e.g. to a brothel in Nevada or Amsterdam).

Comment: @SamIam - (4) No more intrusive than IRS knowing details of every single transaction I make, given that the device is PRIVATE and nobody else has access to it. Whether it's hugely objectionable, it's debatable. In 2014, people don't seem to take sexual privacy very seriously among younger generation. Even if I grant you that you're right, that's still 3 methods I came up when you asked for them, so please do address those.

Answer (score 3):

No inherent origin required. Money as the ultimate fungible commodity has been recognized since ancient Mesopotamia.

If philosophers have explored precisely why we don't simply break athletes' legs or cut up pretty people's faces instead, you'd have to dig into their more esoteric works.

By redistributing money, the rich have to reduce consumption patterns (assumed to be implicitly unfair) to maintain liquidity. Redistributing the wealth produced instead of the modes of production is considered less of an upheaval to a society; even if the inherent unfairness of idle rich isn't fully addressed in this fashion.

Money is afforded especial attention because we don't live in a command economy.

Comment: I'm glad you're so dismissive, but in prior ages, money was NOT equalized this way.

Comment: @DVK Are you referring to a time when money was not fungible or a time when wealth distribution didn't occur?

Comment: the latter. I gave examples in my question (Hoachadel were not taxed, in Holy Roman Empire. I'm pretty sure that applied to many other countries of the era).

Comment: @DVK Either way, once we started thinking about how to reduce inequality, the fungibility of money was going to be main way to treat the symptoms. Incidentally, equality through other mechanisms was considered; such as compulsory education to equalise intellect and eugenics to equalise physical health. In theory, as suggested in Peter Hamilton's works, equality of wealth is sufficient to equalise physical attributes once those attributes become modifiable (e.g. genetic engineering).

Comment: In any case, money was the only workable lever available in the 19th century and considered the only self evident one; hence the lack of explicit rumination in the mainstream literature.

Answer (score 2):

I think the culprit has to be those utilitarian economists. In the end, equality isn't about money, per se, it's about happiness, fulfillment, and the ability to meet one's wants. In the 1900s Jeremy Bentham and succeeding economists theorized the idea of utility as an empirical sum of all these pleasures. Unfortunately, it proved completely impossible to actually measure. Daniel Reed gives a good summation [in a paper on Utilitarians](http://eprints.lse.ac.uk/22750/1/04064.pdf):

> ...while pleasures and pains constituted the metaphysical 
>   foundation of utilitarian economics, neither their measurement nor even their 
>   existence was central to their methods. Rather, choice behavior was assumed to 
>   reflect, however roughly, the quantity of utility derived from a choice. Marshall 
>   (1920), indeed, was explicit about what assumptions were being made, and their 
>   potential shortcomings ...
>
> "It cannot be too much insisted that to measure directly, or per se,
>   either desires  or the satisfaction which results from their
>   fulfilment is impossible, if not  inconceivable. If we could, we
>   should have two accounts to make up, one of  desires, and the other of
>   realized satisfactions. And the two might differ  considerably. … But
>   as neither of them is possible, we fall back on the  measurement which
>   economics supplies, of the motive or moving force to  action: and we
>   make it serve, with all its faults, both for the desires which  prompt
>   activities and for the satisfactions that result from them." (Book III,
>   Chapter III, Footnote 57).

So economists settled for the idea of revealed preference; that people prefer what they choose. Since the easiest way (perhaps the only reliable way) to measure what people prefer is by what they buy, the idea of utility became intertwined with money. Later attempts to create a more equal distribution of utility fell to a more equal distribution of money.

Thus, to reconcile your examples, egalitarians don't actually care about equalizing height or demagoguery (or money), they care about the additional utility from being tall or that being a successful demagogue brings. Since measuring the extra utility of tallness or demagoguery is practically impossible, they settle with the flawed assumption that tallness and demagoguery bring money(which brings utility) and redistribute some of that.

But what of sex? Sex also probably correlates with money(it did in both examples from the question), but this relationship could be made much easier by allowing prostitution. Inherent to many cultures and perhaps even human biology is the idea of monogamy. In places where monogamy is culturally enforced, it wouldn't make sense for that society's redistributists to allow any sort of redistribution of sex, as that wouldn't be seen as increasing utility (defying the earlier assumption that choice=utility, but politicians generally aren't concerned with being completely consistent). In places where monogamy isn't enforced, there is no reason for prostitution to be illegal. In these societies money and sex can interchange freely according to individuals preferences strengthening money's use as a reasonable proxy for utility.

"The ideas of economists and political philosophers, both when they are right and when they are wrong, are more powerful than is commonly understood. Indeed the world is ruled by little else. Practical men, who believe themselves to be quite exempt from any intellectual influence, are usually the slaves of some defunct economist." -John Maynard Keynes

Answer (score 1):

Money is not considered to be special in political thinking.

We also strive for equality under the law

In most first world countries, law applies to just about everyone in it's jurisdiction the same, no matter how tall, pretty, or rich you are.  In America, this is officially codified by section 1 of the 14th amendment.

> Section 1. All persons born or naturalized in the United States, and
>   subject to the jurisdiction thereof, are citizens of the United States
>   and of the State wherein they reside. No State shall make or enforce
>   any law which shall abridge the privileges or immunities of citizens
>   of the United States; nor shall any State deprive any person of life,
>   liberty, or property, without due process of law; nor deny to any
>   person within its jurisdiction the equal protection of the laws.

---

As far as advantages in physical build go, there are still laws to enforce that equality.

you might have heard of the [Americans with Disabilities Act](http://www.dol.gov/dol/topic/disability/ada.htm), and other similar laws, which require some businesses to have handicapped parking spaces, ramps, and other accommodations.  It doesn't matter much whether or not you used money to get those accommodations with money so long as they're there.

---

There are also programs that provide housing to those who can't afford to pay for their own, forcing people with a lot of housing(landlords) to provide it for a miniscule rent.

> It's allowing people to pay miniscule amount for an apartment in the
>   middle of Manhattan that the landlord would ordinarily charge 5-10x
>   more for (the state does NOT pay the rest! They merely force the
>   landlord to keep the rent low).

---

As far as sex goes, you said that you can come up with numerous possible solutions that may be intrusive, but not hugely objectionable or offensive to modern sensibilities, but I don't believe you, and I won't until you actually do come up with one.

Transferring talent is similar, except you physically can't do it, at least not in the way of taking it from someone and giving it to somebody else.

---

As far as material goods go, they're equated to money, because if you have money, you can buy material goods such as land, food, housing, shelter, transportation, etc, with money.  In fact, that's classically what money is for.  It's a credit for buying things.

So programs that redistribute money also effectively redistribute access to food, housing, shelter and other needs

Comment: -1 - food is NOT being taken specifically from people who eat too much. It's being taken from people who have "too much money", contradicting your assertion that money isn't treated specially. When I'm hungry all day because I worked non-stop, they don't have a program to take someone who east too much and give me their food. Food stamps are NOT about redistributing food, they are about redistributing money, in a way that feels and sounds less objectionable to people who dislike welfare "because people blow that money on drugs and other non-essential".

Comment: Also, application of the law is extremely special and (while I admit I didn't take the pain to clearly state that) outside the scope of the question since it's not a zero-sum material good. Equal application of the law to one person does NOT change its application to others (e.g. if you avoid hanging someone for stealing bread, you don't go hang another person to balance things out from that change).

Comment: @DVK Well, at least **you** admit that application of the law is so special that it blows money out of the water

Comment: ... to prove my point about food stamps, you can gauge sentiment via a poll, to see how many people supporting food stamps as a desirable program would agree to replace it with cash equivalent.

Comment: @DVK and you also seem to clearly understand the concept that access to money implies access to food

Comment: No. You didn't seem to read that comment. There are PLENTY of days when I go a lot hungrier than an average poor person because I didn't have time to get food or to eat it. They are somewhat correllated, but not identical. Treating food specially would imply very specifically, taking food (not money) away from people who have more than average food (not money), and giving it to someone who is hungry. That includes taking food away from poor person who eats 10000 calories a day at McDonalds - MORE than from someone like me.

Comment: the closest equivalent in real life I can think of to treating food specially would be the "raskilachivanie" program of taking the food from prosperous peasants in early Soviet Russia/USSR

Comment: The specific fallacy your answer makes is that money guarantees food. It does not. It merely helps facilitate food. TIME is as required as money, so the person with ample free time is quite plausibly more food-rich compared to a person with no free time at all, asssuming both have enough money to buy SOME food - which in USA includes nearly 100% population after welfare/foodstamps.

Comment: counterexample to shelter==money: subsidized rent housing in NYC. We have people who are basically living a multimillionair lifestyle in terms of real estate they have available to them, while being very poor. I make more than many of them but couldn't afford even 1/10th of their living space in Manhattan; and therefore am forced to significantly degrade my quality of life by commuting 3+ hours a day. Again, if it was REALLY about housing and not money, this situation would be considered inequality, instead of a Good Thing (because said renters are poor)

Comment: @DVK So you're using a subsidy that helps people pay for housing as a "counterexample" of how money can be used to buy housing....

Comment: subsidized housing in NYC is NOT your average "helping people pay for housing". It's allowing people to pay miniscule amount for an apartment in the middle of Manhattan that the landlord would ordinarily charge 5-10x more for (the state does NOT pay the rest! They merely force the landlord to keep the rent low). For an example you as non-NewYorker can easily relate to, imagine if welfare covered purchasing a yacht, or food stamps covered caviar and champagne. Except not with money, merely with political law forcing the providers to provide those things to the poor who qualify

Comment: @Samn it is precisely the case where someone has access to "unfairly large" amount of housing goods, yet is monetary poor.

Comment: @DVK okay  I've added that bit about housing to my answer

Comment: I'll grant you ADA, but it is **extremely limited**, and for example doesn't address height inequality which the question highlighted. I can add links showing HUGE discrepancy (something like $1000 if not more per inch of height). Even **more importantly**, ADA is again NOT really about equalizing - you do NOT take money from all non-disabled persons, you take money from the rich (as an example, if it was not about money, you could force poor people to contribute in-kind by helping provide free labor to build handicap-accessible ramps, at least where tax money is used for them).

Comment: In short, a valid example would show a specific monetary attribute very specifically and targetedly being denied to those who have that attribute in abundance, making pains to NOT only do so from the rich people who have that attribute; and grant it to those who have a lack of attribute, again independent of wealth. None of your examples fit.

Comment: I added the clarification explaining why I am rejecting all of your examples to the question. Hope the wording is clear enough.

Comment: here's a refined list of 2 sexual favors proposals: (1) Detect when a man is unfairly popular with women (according to [this experiment](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/violetblue/ten-fake-profiles-one-okcupid-experiment-okcupid-on-trial/1405), good looking ones get 20-40x more responses) by amount of likes, visits, or messages sent first or returned. After a specified amount, that account is required canceled by dating service and that IP blocked. There's pretty clear if less-scientifically-rigorous research indicating that this would have measurable equalizing effect.

Comment: ... Similar thing with bars for offline situation - any man leaving with unfair amount of partners gets barred after a threshold is reached, by law

Comment: (2) Somewhat more controversial, mandatory sterilization for a male who fathers >N out of wedlock children. Given advances in genetic analysis, and the fact that most women give birth in a hospital, it's fairly implementable within the next 5 years

Comment: Re: your housing edit: Sorry but that's BS. Landlords do NOT have "more housing". Housing that they provide is **NOT their housing**, it's their business asset that just happens to be a house. Often they don't even own it personally. What you just proposed is akin to implementing food fairness by forcing all food stores and restaurants to feed the poor for free (Or even closer, akin to telling the banks to give free money to the poor because banks have money on their balance sheet due to their line of business); and nowhere NEAR what the question discusses.

Answer (score 0):

It would appear you can use the law of diminishing returns from basic Economics to prove that a curve representing the value currently being received by a person should be weighted so that the fewer dollars he has, the greater the value he will receive per additonal dollar. A dollar for potatoes is worth more than a dollar for a couple feet flown in an airplane (Those on airplanes right now might disagree with me).

It follows that its fungibility makes money the only commodity where you can enforce a transfer to another person and create a theoretical net gain. If you transfer shoes, they may not fit; if you transfer wives and husbands, they may not match; even if you transfer crude oil, it might be of inferior quality. Money is the only mathematically pure commodity. If you transfer gold, gold might not be legal tender but certainly meets the criteria of money, it simply fell out of use.

Grading how strongly you would weigh the cost of the transfer itself likely determines where you live on the political spectrum.

Comment: "if you transfer wives and husbands, they may not match" - given divorce rates in USA, I'm tempted to quip that randomly transfering spouses can't make situation with good matching any worse :)

Comment: @DVK Feel free to write an Alternet article about your new proposal.

Comment: Those who would apply the law of diminishing returns to wealth overlook something very important: some people have the skill and inclination to use wealth as capital to produce more wealth, while other people do not. The marginal value of a dollar to someone who would use it to generate more wealth is greater than the marginal value of a dollar to someone who would not do so, and those with the ability and inclination to use marginal wealth as additional capital to produce more wealth tend as a consequence to be wealthier than those who don't.  The fact that the wealthy have little "need"...

Comment: ...to spend marginal wealth on their own consumption increases rather than decreases the value of any marginal wealth they acquire.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find an answer because you just set up a strawman based on your own ideology. People have been arguing for equality in many domains, most notably political rights (”one man one vote”), power in the workplace or access to land, healthcare or education.

Your examples are also wholly unconvincing. To discuss only the one about tall men, beautiful women and success in the work place, people have in fact been arguing for “equality of chances” or “opportunity” for ages but how do you propose to enforce that? Ensure everybody is the same size? Force everyone to work in a cubicle so that they can't see who they are working with?

In a free-market trade-based society, mitigating excessive income differences is the most realistic way to deal with inequality (and it would be required anyway), while preserving freedom but it does not imply that the people who support such measures only care about money.

If money has a special role, it's mostly because it's fungible. Most inequalities (say success in the workplace or lack of food) can be most efficiently addressed by transferring money. But that's not a matter of political thinking, it's just a result of the structure of the economy.

Comment: "One man one vote" being ontopic implies that some men have MORE than one vote and those excess votes are transfered to those without. I don't recall that scenario happening in recent political history - at least in USA, AFAIK nobody ever had >1 vote. Power in the workplace - THAT one actually shows promise. Zero-sum situation. Access to land - no. You don't confiscate land from those who have lots of it to give to **anyone** (independent of wealth) who doesn't. You don't take healthcare or education from those who have "too much" either. It helps if you **read** the question.

Comment: Why not confiscate land? That's what land reform in many country was about. But all that is beside the point, the fact is people have argued for equality in different domains and money is not “singled out”.

Comment: the fact that there's no well known solution to the problem, doesn't mean that the problem doesn't exist or should not be addressed. Therefore, the fact that it isn't raised or discussed is wholly irrelevant to the fact that it doesn't have an obvious clear-cut solution, but that people don't bother perceiving it as the problem.

Comment: when was the last time someone confiscated land **independently of wealth** without abolishing private ownership of land in the first case? (litmus test of independence: a wealthy industrialist with NO land gets MORE land as a result of the "fairness" confiscation than a poor peasant that already has land). I very carefully spelled this out in the question

Comment: @DVK Oh, but inequality in this and other domains is often discussed, as I already wrote… Yet, it's quite relevant to note that dealing with income inequality as a way to empower people to make their own choices is both more realistic and more comprehensive than, e.g., micro-managing the workplace. That many thinkers discuss the former therefore does not mean they don't care about the latter, as you seemed to imply.

Comment: @DVK But the distinction is completely artificial, for the reasons I and others already gave. This might make sense from your perspective but it's not the way proponents of equality think about this so you can't expect anybody to lay out the origin or justification for an idea they don't agree they hold…